# Can I read the CPU temperature from a register

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, raspberry-pi

I am working on raspberry pi b+ and I would like to read the CPU temperature in a kernel file. The thermal sensor is defined in the device tree:

```
thermal: thermal@7e212000 {
            compatible = "brcm,bcm2835-thermal";
            reg = <0x7e212000 0x8>;
            clocks = <&clocks BCM2835_CLOCK_TSENS>;
            #thermal-sensor-cells = <0>;
            status = "disabled";
        };
```

So I know the register address and length. I am wondering if I could get the cpu temperature by reading this register directly in the kernel file.

Comment: What is `kernel file`?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-4.19.y/kernel/sched/core.c) is the file I mentioned, I need to get the CPU temperature in it.